# ios swift app development: UIScrollview not scrolling contents and working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4, vertical-scrolling

I am using a UIScrollView inside my root layout and I am trying to make its children inside scroll but for some reason it is not working.

Upon search I found possible solutions to set -

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

and

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: self.view.width, height: 2000)
```

but they both don't work

Here's a screenshot of my current layout along with the applied constraints and scrollview properties from the inspector panel -

[image: scroll view properties]
[image: scroll view constraints]

Constraints for inner contents of scrollview -

[image: view1]
[image: view2]
[image: view3]

Can someone here please suggest what am I doing wrong or any other suggestion that can help fix or debug this issue here

Comment: You see those red lines on the top and bottom of your scroll view? That means that there are conflicts in your constraints. I'm guessing it wants you to add constraints for the content inside your scrollview. Could you add details about the contents inside your scrollview and the constraints applied to the contents, if any?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog updated the post with the inner content's constraints

Comment: Hmm, thats an interesting UI layout. What I would do is take all 3 subviews inside the UIScrollView and embed them into a single container UIView. Then set the container UIView to have 0 for top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints. Also set the container UIView to have equal width and equal height as the UIScrollView. And set the equal height constraint's priority as 750. Let me know if that works - you will have to add constraints back to all 3 subviews once it gets embedded in the container UIView.

Comment: tried embedding them in the uiview (https://ibb.co/T8Dgppg), scrollview is still not working and now I am not even able to click on any buttons inside my player controls. Checked the user interaction enabled setting for both scrollview and my uiview and both of them are active. Anyways still, not able to get the scrolling view working

Comment: That's because you haven't added anything to the scroll view.

Comment: What do you mean ? I see there are 2 stackviews and a UIView inside the scrollview and also tried embedding these 3 inside a uiview inside the scrollview as suggested by @MSU_Bulldog

Comment: Check my answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222027/using-a-scroll-view-to-zoom-in-an-image-with-swift/51222296#51222296 for a step by step scrollview implementation

Answer (score 1):

Content inside the ScrollView must need its height and width.
In order to scroll, the content height must be greater than phone screen.
What i am suggesting here adjust constraints properly.

I.e.
Place All your UI elements inside UIView inside ScrollView.
Add constraints from UIView to ScrollView:- Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing, Equal Width.

Add constraints to all your UI elements to UIView so that UIView will have definite height.

Comment: Yes, I tried by adding fixed heights to all elements and wrapped them inside a UIView but still the scrollview isn't working. Could it be because the content height < phone screen in portrait mode but content height > phone screen in landscape mode. Do I need to make any changes for it to become scrollable once the orientation changes ?